# View all TODO items in Visual Studio using GhostDoc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, todo, ghostdoc

I'm also using [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) in Visual Studio 2008. How do I view all to-do items and if that's a function already in Visual Studio or in GhostDoc (the documentation tool that I use)?

Answer (score 186):

If you are referring to TODOs that are defined with the **// TODO** comments, open the Task List and set it to the Comments filter.

[image: Visual Studio - Task List - Comments]

Also be careful with GhostDoc. Always read the comment that was generated. I remember that older versions would generate comments like: "Toes the string" for a method like ToString().

Comment: oh yea, I always read the comment.  half the time I modify but it helps me start out so I love it.  I think VS has a simplar auto gen XML comments too?   I just like the stubbing out of the XML comment structure and Ghostdoc does help a lot with the text ..but yea you do have to modify it if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, if your TODOs use a different string than `TODO`, you can make those show upin the task list as well by going to `Tools->Options->Task List` and adding items to the "Token list:" there (along with priority).

Comment: Visual Studio will generate a small comment block when you type three slashes: ///, that's about it. GhostDoc is nice, when used properly, sometimes people get too lazy using it, saves a lot of typing though :). Also if you're interested in generating documentation, check out Microsoft SandCastle.

Comment: Also check out my free AtomineerUtils addin (www.atomineerutils.com) - it's like GhostDoc but does considerably more and produces better comments so there's less to clean up manually afterwards.

Comment: @Zyphrax Image broken!

Comment: @Nenotlep thanks for letting me know. I've replaced it.

Comment: @Zyphrax 'Toes the string' made me lol, I remember reading a comment 'This code was written by tool' - makes me smile every time I remember it :)

Comment: @Liufa It probably rocked :)

Answer (score 26):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has a nice ToDo explorer to get an overview of all todos -or custom keywords- comments.

Comment: This is nicer than the built in ux for larger projects. By default, the TODO items are organized in the same way as the solution. The default view is just ordered alphabetically by file name containing the comment.

Comment: I didn't realize resharper has this after using it all these years.  I like this option as it organizes better.

Answer (score 7):

Note that in Express versions like *Visual Web Developer 2010 Express* and *Visual C# Express 2010*, you need to be in Expert mode to enable the task list. Expert mode is at menu *Tools* → *Settings* → *Expert Mode*.

Then the option to open the list is in menu *View* → *Task List*.