# Where does Visual Studio store the bookmarks and what format are they stored in?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to get at the stored bookmarks file (or file section, if the bookmarks are stored in a file along with other stuff).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203199/bookmarks-visual-studio

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The bookmarks are stored in the solution's SUO file. It also contains other "per developer" settings

Its binary format, so I don't think you could export them easily, unless you just copy the entire SUO with all the other settings

Comment: Thanks surfen!.  Too bad it is binary. I was expecting a simple XML file.

Comment: @Mig You might be interested in this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052/tool-to-view-the-contents-of-the-solution-user-options-file-suo

Comment: are there some good practices to share bookmarks with source control?

Comment: Aren't those guys from microsoft one of a kind!?