# How to backup bookmarks in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I find bookmarks very handy and helps me with code navigation.

I found this [Exporting and importing bookmarks in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203199/exporting-and-importing-bookmarks-in-visual-studio)

But I cannot find .suo in VS 2019. So how do I backup my bookmarks in VS 2019

Comment: Look into the hidden folder named _.vs_

Comment: See the discussion on this previous question:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203199/exporting-and-importing-bookmarks-in-visual-studio