# Visual Studio TODO / Task List not showing up

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio 2010 Express

I have a task list open and on filter setting comments.

It does not show any inline

```
// TODO whatever
```

comments at all, whether project or file specific. Any idea why? Do I need to set the tokens manually or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [View all TODO items in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165120/view-all-todo-items-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [this Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551326/visual-studio-2010-c-task-list-problem), it's turned off by default for C++ for performance reasons.

To enable this feature go to *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Text Editor* -> *C/C++* -> *Formatting* -> *Miscellaneous*, and set *Enumerate Comment Tasks* to **True**.

Comment: Yes but both in VS 2010 and VS 2012 you only see those TODOs which are contained in the currently open files. Is there another switch to get all the TODOs in a solution?

Comment: @CsabaToth No, I don't think there is. For a large project this would probably result in a huge number of items and could impact perf. I suspect that's why this is not enabled.

Comment: It helped me to. Sadly it causes VS 2012 to hang sometimes with "something in background" message.

Comment: for me in VS13 it was in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> View-> Miscellaneous`

Comment: @sami1592 for me(VS15 - Community) that option was set True by default but it reports only opened source files. The description says **"Scan open source files for TODO... and report them in the Task List window"**. Is it same for you?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VS2015(Community).

For me, VS seems to search tasks only in opened source files.

Pressing `Ctrl`+`K`+`H` adds the current line into the TaskLists and it wouldn't be hidden even if the source file is not opened.

You can do this from `Edit`->`Bookmarks`->`Add Task List Shortcut` also.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VS2017(Community).

My **Enumerate Comment Tasks** already set to **True**, still not working.

However, after I set it to **False** -> press **OK** button to close **Option dialog** -> open **Option dialog** again -> set the flag to **True**, it works now.