# Visual C++ TODO Task List not showing elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, todo

The // TODO comments and other custom defined are not showing up in task list in Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate, x64, sp1) even activating the option in configuration, as is told in that post:

[Visual Studio TODO / Task List not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794314/visual-studio-todo-task-list-not-showing-up)

I know that only works on opened files that have todo comments, but even with an opened file that have them I get an empty list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already changed *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Miscellaneous -> Enumerate Comment Tasks* to **True**...

Did you also change the box in Visual studio's *Task List* from **User Tasks** to **Comments** ?

Comment: ohh I stupid, had the window at one side and didn't saw that listbox, than you very much!

Comment: No problem.  Had the same issue last week.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a solution (.sln) open, not just a file or project within a solution. Even a .csproj or .vbproj file won't cut it.