# Task List in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio

Since there isn't a page for 2012 and 2010 is pretty close I used [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zce12xx2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I wrote the below but I see an empty task list. How do I properly do this? Note: "Enumerate Comment Tasks" is set to true.

```
void myfunc() {
    ...
    // TODO Fix this function.
    ...
```

Comment: Try a colon at the end of the todo word... TODO:

Comment: @MotoSV: Didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

VS 2012, 2010, 2008: When you switch to the Task List window, the topmost control is a drop-down list. Switch it from "User tasks" to "Comments". Your TODOs in your comments should appear. In case of C++ there are some constraints, look at my specific C++ answer.

Comment: It's true for VS2008 and VS2010, just checked.

Comment: Note you can also configure which tokens show up under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Task List.  The defaults are TODO, HACK, and UNDONE.

Comment: oh snap I did not see that down arrpw/dropdown. wow. BUT for some reason (@#$%^!!) it still doesn't list. I did a rebuild and I don't see it there. I'm using C++ if that helps. +1 cause now i'm looking at the right place

Comment: @acidzombie24: I tried it with a C++ project now, and it doesn't show up. That's weird. Hopefully it's not another feature which is supported for C# but not for C++.

Comment: @CsabaToth: The thing is, I see it enabled in the C++ formatting section. :x. Maybe its broken in 2012

Comment: @acidzombie24: It works for me now, but with limitations: just for the currently open files. I guess this is by design, for performance reasons? See my specific C++ answer.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ the enumeration is turned off by default for performance reasons: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794314/visual-studio-todo-task-list-not-showing-up). See also: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/5d229fd3-e501-40c1-a236-0cb490a83fff/). But if I enable the switch mentioned in the other StackOverflow topic, I still didn't see all of the TODOs. I have to actually open up a file with TODOs, and then I see only the TODOs in the currently open files.

Comment: Maybe there's another switch somewhere to enumerate everything? I have to tell that I was on the other side too wen I was a CAD developer: so humongous project that every "feature" was bogging. So I can understand it's turned off. But it should be able to be turned on.

Comment: Workaround can be: Find in Files search with Match Case, Whole Words for "TODO". Visual Studio's Find window is very ergonomic, I just double click and I jump to the line.